# MVC View get's compilation error (CS0246) when referenced assembly built as console application. When it built as Class Library - it works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a solution. First project contains entity framework models, output type is Console application. Other project is frontend, asp.net mvc 5 application that have CRUD views for entities from the first project. First project referenced from the second project, also I added dependent assembly in web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="VolLoader" publicKeyToken="null" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But when I access view that uses entity from this assembly, I get view compilation error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'VolLoader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:



Line 29:     
Line 30:     
Line 31:     public class _Page_Views_JobMon_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<VolLoader.Data.JobToWatch>> {
Line 32:         
Line 33: #line hidden
```

Adding namespace () to the web.config in views folder causes compilation errors on every view.

Assembly is copied to output.

**But when I change Output type of the first project to the Class Library, it works, no compilation errors.** I can't understand why? Does anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found why this is happening. I'm not 100% sure, but I can't recompile system.web.dll to prove it.
I found this code in system.web.dll:

```
namespace System.Web.Compilation
{
    /// <summary>Provides a container for building an assembly from one or more virtual paths within an ASP.NET project.</summary>
    public class AssemblyBuilder
......
}
```

Line 381:

```
internal CompilerParameters GetCompilerParameters()
{
    CompilerParameters compilerParameters = this._compilerType.CompilerParameters;
    string text = this._tempFiles.TempDir;
    if (this.CultureName != null)
    {
        text = Path.Combine(text, this.CultureName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(text);
        compilerParameters.OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(text, this.OutputAssemblyName + ".resources.dll");
    }
    else
    {
        compilerParameters.OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(text, this.OutputAssemblyName + ".dll");
    }
```

As you can see, it takes only dlls:

```
compilerParameters.OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(text, this.OutputAssemblyName + ".dll");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your first project can not be built as a console application (Do you have static `Main` method?. And because first project can not be built, second project fails to build because missing references - i.e. missing assembly for the first project.

Why do you want your EF models be contained within console application?

Comment: First project is built successfully. Moreover, I'm already using this exe on other machine to perform some recurring tasks. everything is built fine, exe is copied to output folder.

Comment: In that case this is a restriction of MVC engine. You'll need to separate your models into a separate project and reference that from console app and from web app.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did. But what is the explanation of this? I does not make any sense to me, but Iєму spent couple of hours of probes and mistakes so I want to understand the reason so next time I will know what is happening. thanks

Comment: what happens if you change reference path to assembly to absolute path with *.exe in your second *.csproj?